# Invoke a rule upon form validation

Tags: rules, users

Is it possible to to invoke a rule this way?

So far I have not had any luck?

```
/* Implementation of hook_form_alter*/

function login_auth_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {

  $form['#validate'][] = 'ea_login'; 
  }
}

/* implementation of hook_form_validate */

function ea_login($form, &$form_state) {

  $response = rules_invoke('rules_my_rule', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
/* Implementation of hook_form_alter*/

function login_auth_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {


if ($form_id == 'user_login') {

        $form['#validate'][] = 'ea_login';
    }
}

/* implementation of hook_form_validate */
function ea_login($form, &$form_state) {

        $response = "SUCCESS message";

      rules_invoke_component('rules_display_a_message',$response);

}
```